# A book about a boy in King Arthur's court

Tags: story-identification, books

In the book a boy has a wooden amulet with a unicorn on it. Merlin warns him not to tell this to Arthur. Somewhere in the series there is a tower with a mad woman in it who scribbles onto a wall. There is also a siege of the castle where the boy devises a strategy where they build a second wall in the courtyard and they let the assailants through but close the gate and then slaughter them all.

I read the book when I was a child more than ten years ago and it came to mind recently.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Is there any fantasy or science fiction in the book?

Comment: It could be T.H.White's "The Sword in the Stone" except that in that tale the boy is Arthur himself -- although it is only revealed later: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_in_the_Stone_(novel)

Comment: @user14111 besides one of the most famous wizards in history?

Comment: Is this the movie "a kid in king arthur's court", based off of Connecticut yankee?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/162898.A_Connecticut_Yankee_in_King_Arthur_s_Court) by Mark Twain? In the book, someone from the present day wakes up in King Arthur's time and uses his modern knowledge to his advantage to become the King's chief problem-solver. I don't remember enough of the book to recognize the particular scenes you mention. However, devising a clever strategy to protect the castle sounds consistent with what I do remember of the book.

> The novel is a comedy that sees sixth-century England and its medieval culture through Hank Morgan's view; he is a nineteenth-century resident of Hartford, Connecticut, who, after a blow to the head, awakens to find himself inexplicably transported back in time to early medieval England where he meets King Arthur himself. Hank, who had an image of that time that had been colored over the years by romantic myths, takes on the task of analyzing the problems and sharing his knowledge from 1300 years in the future to try to modernize, Americanize, and improve the lives of the people.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Connecticut_Yankee_in_King_Arthur%27s_Court)</sub>

[image: A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court front cover]

Comment: I have my doubts on this being the answer. The main character (the eponymous Yankee) is an adult in Twain's book. There probably have been "kid" versions. There definitely have been for the movies.

Comment: It's been a few years since I read Connecticut Yankee, but I'm reasonably sure none of the scenes described in the question appear in it.

Comment: hi, the book you refer to isn't anything like the book i have in memory. But thank you for your efforts

Comment: I also think this unlikely -- the mentioned stratagem, with the inner wall to create a killing trap, doesn't appear in that book.  There's also no evidence that the boy is from the the present/future.

Comment: Also, Merlin was an antagonist in _Connecticut Yankee_. The boy would have had to have been Clarence.

Answer (score 1):

Is the book called *[Gwydion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3473344796)* by Peter Schwindt? I was searching for the name of the book for a long time too and stumbled over your question and thought I'd come back to try to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If you believe this might be the answer, you should describe it and demonstrate how it matches the question.

Comment: I haven't found a summary online, and the books seem to have only been released in German and Catalan.

Comment: You are amazing, that is the book I have been looking for. Thank you.